# mariadb procedure phpmyadmin error

Tags: stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Getting following error while creating stored procedure in PHPmyadmin sql box:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') BEGIN DECLARE ref_id varchar(10)' at line 1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_tree(IN id varchar)
 BEGIN
 DECLARE ref_id varchar(10);
 DECLARE userid varchar(10);
 SET userid = id;
 SET ref_id='';
 SELECT ref_id into ref_id 
 FROM user WHERE user_id=id ;
 create TEMPORARY  table IF NOT EXISTS temp_table as (select * from user where 1='');
 truncate table temp_table;
 WHILE ref_id <> '' DO
   insert into temp_table select * from user WHERE user_id=userid;
   SET userid = ref_id;
   SET ref_id='';
   SELECT ref_id into ref_id
   FROM user WHERE user_id=userid;
 END WHILE;
 select * from temp_table;
 END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue resolved by adding following delimiter as:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_tree(IN id varchar(10)) 
BEGIN
 DECLARE ref_id varchar(10);
 DECLARE userid varchar(10);
 SET userid = id;
 SET ref_id='';
 SELECT ref_id into ref_id 
 FROM user WHERE user_id=id ;
 create TEMPORARY  table IF NOT EXISTS temp_table as (select * from user where 1='');
 truncate table temp_table;
 WHILE ref_id <> '' DO
   insert into temp_table select * from user WHERE user_id=userid;
   SET userid = ref_id;
   SET ref_id='';
   SELECT ref_id into ref_id
   FROM user WHERE user_id=userid;
 END WHILE;
 select * from temp_table;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: A note just to prevent future readers from getting confused. Changing delimiters won't anyhow solve or even affect the _initial_ problem described in the question; with or without it, you'll still get the same exact error at line 1. Only after you actually fix the wrong parameter (as it has been done in this answer), the delimiter will become important, if it's not changed to a non-semicolon earlier in your session, it will naturally cause a syntax error, but an entirely different one, at line 3, where the first semicolon appears.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the procedure parameter -- you cannot have varchar without the length. It should be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_tree(IN id varchar(10))
 BEGIN
 ...
```

(or whatever length you want there, but 10 seems to be a reasonable choice).